# Having issues in running python code in Terminal with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, import, terminal

Hello thank you for taking a look at my question here.

I am new to coding and am learning python. I am using Linux, specifically Ubuntu.
I wrote a simple tkinter-based application which when launched displays a countdown to a particular date and then has a button to click to close the window. I have run this application in PyCharm and it works perfectly there. I also runs perfectly in IDLE. in both, tkinter imports and runs just fine.

I located the .py file for my aplication in the terminal and used

```
$ chmod +x main.py
```

then

```
$ ./main.py
```

I get the response

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ./main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 9, in <module>
    import tkinter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Most similar questions I have managed to find suggest that tkinter must be installed, but certainly it would appear that tkinter IS installed, it ran in PyCharm and in IDLE, I have followed the directories listed to see that they are in fact on the system, I have run

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ pip install tk
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: tk in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.1.0)
```

I have run

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ python3
Python 3.8.5 (default, Feb  4 2021, 18:26:47) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

everything I do seems to comfirm tkinter is installed yet will not import in Terminal.
Any help?

**update**
First of all I want to thank everyone who has commented so far, your insights have certainly led me to progress here.

I have discovered that I have 2 seperate installations of python 3.8.5

I showed above what happened when I used $python3 and >>>import tkinter in terminal. I just now tried calling the other installation in terminal by it's file path and issuing the same command:

```
root@ubuntu:/# /usr/bin/python3.8
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>> exit()
```

tkinter imports.
I do not get the above error.

I knew I had to have a working tkinter somewhere on my system because PyCharm and IDLE both successfully ran it. terminal however, still fails to import it when I simply attempt to run the .py file.

So now I suppose that my issue becomes how do I remove the Feb 4 installation and keep the Jul 28 installation, or how do I get the Feb 4 installation to import tkinter.

Comment: `pip install tk` installs `TensorKit`, not `tkinter`.  You need to install via system package manager: `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`.

Comment: $ sudo apt-get install python3-tk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-tk is already the newest version (3.8.5-1~20.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 61 not upgraded.

Comment: Is the folder where tkinter is installed listed in your `pythonpath`?

Comment: @pavel sorry, I'm not sure what pythonpath means. does that mean whether it is installed in the same directory? tkinter is installed in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/tkinter/  - where can I find pythonpath?

Comment: `pythonpath` is one of environmental variables that lives on your system and contains locations of directories where Python packages are installed.

Comment: I am still looking into  this, but I think the answer to my question may well be here, as I said, tkinter is in usr/local/lib/python3.8/tkinter/
$ echo $PATH gave me "/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin" - nothong leads to usr/local/lib...

Comment: The tkinter module is located inside `/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter` in my Ubuntu.  Did you build the Python yourself?

Comment: @acw1668 I installed python 3.8.5 from a .tgz archive downloaded from  
     wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.5/Python-3.8.5.tgz

Comment: It appears that I have 2 installations of python 3.8.5  
One is named python3  
One is named python3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I determined I had system python in /usr/bin/ and a self-compiled python of the same version in /usr/local/bin/ when I uninstalled the self-compiled installation, and ram my application from terminal everything worked perfectly, tkinter imported and my application ran from terminal exactly as it had from both IDEs I have used.

I uninstalled according to these instructions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190794/uninstall-python-installed-by-compiling-source simply replacing references to 2.7 with 3.8

thank you to everybody who commented, you were a great help and @acw1668 in particular, your comment led to me indifying that I had installations under both file paths. Much thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar Problem once on ubuntu, that `pip` was linked to the `python2` installation, have you tried to work with `pip3`:

```
pip3 install tkinter
```